# make field required depending on another text box

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 text boxes one for email and one for Name. If text is entered in email I want to make Name required field. How can I do this using  .net validation controls?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the custom validator:

[Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic7)